# C# assigning textbox contents to specific elements of an array causes some elements to be null

Tags: c#

Hey guys so I have a userControl file which prompts to user to enter their information in which creates a text file with the information to a directory. I created multiple textboxes which have the same code. The array "info" was declared like this

```
    private string[] oof = new string[19];
```

All of the textboxes are coded like this below.

```
    private void TextBox0_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) // First Name
    {
        info[0] = textBox0.Text;

    }

    private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //Last Name
    {
        info[1] = textBox1.Text;

    }
    .....
```

The method I used to create the text file is

```
       private void ButtonCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Create new Profile
       {
       string path = @"C:\Users\J\Desktop\C#\ + profileName + ".txt";




        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
            {

                sw.WriteLine(list[i]);
                sw.Flush();
            }

            sw.Close();
            sw.Dispose();      
        }


    }
```

This code correctly creates the text file with the desired name to the right directory but the content of the text file contains only part of the information that the user provided when I test run it. When I debug the program, I noticed that some of the elements that were being set to the content of different textboxes were 'null' even though it was filled out by the user. It creates the text file but the file only contains part of the user's information not all of it like

```
  first name
  (last name is suppose to be here but its blank)
  address
  phone number
  (state is suppose to be here but its blank)
  city
  ....
```

Comment: They are `null` since you didn't set them. The default value of a string (and thus an entry in a string array) is `null`. If `info[x]` is `null` then you never set `info[x]`. _We can be confident of this since a `Textbox` would be blank rather than `null`._

Comment: `(last name is suppose to be here but its blank)` Please update your post to show the code that sets the last name entry in the array. Also please put a breakpoint on it, and verify whether when the code runs the breakpoint gets hit.

Comment: you should scrap all of that array nonsense and just do sw.WriteLine(textBox0.Text); sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text); etc instead, if that's all the array is used for. Ideally your textbox controls would be named something more appropriate based on the information being input to it, and in the case that the array is being used that you instead create an object with appropriate property names to store those values. If you did that then you might also want to consider serializing the object (JSON?) instead of writing each array value to a new line.